# Result of rendering into texture is empty only with shader

Tags: c#, android, shader, monogame

I think I am very stupid because I can't figure out what causes the issue in this simplest case.

Project type is Windows OpenGL (on Android the issue also persists).

Here is the shader:

```
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
float4 PSTest (float2 TexCoords : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color =  float4 (1, 0, 0, 1);

    return color;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Technique Test
{
    pass Test
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PSTest();
    }
}
```

It works fine if I draw it to the screen with the `Texture` (128x128):

```
        Shader.CurrentTechnique = Shader.Techniques["Test"];
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget (null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.White);

            Batch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque,   
               SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.None, null, Shader);
            Batch.Draw (Texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            Batch.End();
```

[image]

Now I decide to draw it into render target `Output` created by code:

```
new RenderTarget2D (GraphicsDevice, 256, 256, false, 
   SurfaceFormat.Color, DepthFormat.None);
```

Draw code:

```
        // Render into Output
        Shader.CurrentTechnique = Shader.Techniques["Test"];
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget (Output);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.DimGray);

        Batch.Begin (SpriteSortMode.Immediate, BlendState.Opaque,
           SamplerState.PointClamp, DepthStencilState.None, null, Shader);
        Batch.Draw (Texture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        Batch.End();

        // Draw Output
        GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget (null);
        GraphicsDevice.Clear (Color.White);

        Batch.Begin();
        Batch.Draw (Output, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
        Batch.End();
```

But the result is totally absurd:

[image]

I have tried different simplest shaders, SurfaceFormat.HdrBlendable, texture sizes - but nothing helps.

Also I have tried to draw `Texture` (filled with violet) into render target **without shader** (then to the screen) and **it works fine**.

[image]

It seems like I have missed some basics thing about shaders in XNA but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution: https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/530086. The reason is in the shader's input parameters.